# Android cannot figure out where the debug keystore is located

Tags: android

In goggles documentation to To find your SHA-1 fingerprint:

"keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v"

I cannot figure out where the debug keystore is located.  I tried doing a search on debug-keystore using finder, but it came up empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, open Eclipse Preferences, then go to Android > Build. You will see a field with the location of your debug keystore.

For me (Mac OSX) : `/Users/username/.android/debug.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing a search on debug-keystore using finder, but it came up empty

First, the file would be named `debug.keystore`, with a dot (`.`), not a dash (`-`).

Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key):

> The file name is debug.keystore, and is created the first time you build your project. By default, it is stored in the same directory as your Android Virtual Device (AVD) files:
>
> OS X and Linux: ~/.android/
>
> Windows Vista and Windows 7: C:\Users\your_user_name.android\

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to look for an hidden folder `.android` folder that contains your `debug.keystore`

If you are using **Eclipse** you have to follow this path:

```
Preferences > Android > Build > ../android/debug.keystore
```

I wasn't able to find it with **Android Studio** and update edit would be really appreciated :)